# When i open my webbook it need a log in password and i forgot it

Tags: password-recovery

[Is there another way to pass this log in site. Because i have more the 5 years trying to open it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXZon.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

What distro are you running? If it's ubuntu based, when you turn it on you can hold down the shift key as soon as you power it on to access the grub menu. When you are in the grub menu, select advanced options. Then select ubuntu (recovery mode). Now go to the root option. It should be near the bottom. Next, remount the root partition with this command:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Now to reset the password, just type

```
ls /home | grep `^d' | passwd $USER
```

Then type your password and you are done! Hope this helps.